# PHP echo integer value within div tag

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<td>".$value["rating"]."<div class=ratingOutput data-average=".$rates." **data-id="$value["id"]"**></div>".$newline.$rateHere.$starOutput."</td>";
```

I want data-id to be and integer value, but cannot set it to any int for example even if i change the above code to this

```
echo "<td>".$value["rating"]."<div class=ratingOutput data-average=".$rates." **data-id="4"**></div>".$newline.$rateHere.$starOutput."</td>";
```

I get an error as such:

> syntax error, unexpected '$value' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having an error concatenating of your string.

```
echo "<td>".$value["rating"]."<div class=ratingOutput data-average=".$rates." **data-id=". 4 . "**></div>".$newline.$rateHere.$starOutput."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
echo "<td>".$value["rating"]."<div class=ratingOutput data-average=".$rates." **data-id="4"**></div>".$newline.$rateHere.$starOutput."</td>";
```

To this:

```
echo '<td>'.$value['rating'].'<div class="ratingOutput" data-average="' . $rates . '" data-id="' . $value['id'] . '"></div>'.$newline.$rateHere.$starOutput.'</td>';
```

The best way when working with html in PHP is to use single quotes because normally you will be using double quotes for your attribute, by then you will need to escape the double quote. for the attributes you will be using.

Comment: Single quotes indeed mean you don't have to escape your double quotes, but I wouldn't say that's the best way to work with HTML within PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I build HTML in PHP code, I use the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax:

```
echo <<< EOT
  <td>
    {$value['rating']}
    <div class="ratingOutput" data-average="$rates" data-id="4"></div>
    $newline
    $rateHere
    $starOutput
  </td>
EOT;
```

...something like that.

So you don't have to worry about escaping your double-quotes or concatenation.  You can format your HTML so that it's easier to read (perhaps you don't need that `$newline` variable, if it's just a newline character, I can't tell).

(It doesn't have to be used with `echo` either, you can use it in variable assignment `$html = <<< EOT` - no whitespace after your token or it will fail!

If you need the last new-line character in your variable then you need a blank line before your closing token, because the closing character sequence is actually `\nEOT;\n`.

Many examples in articles use `EOT` as the token, but I abandoned that for `_` a long time ago, shorter.